# Problem configuring Network aliases

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ifconfig

Struggling a bit trying to work this out. I'm on a Centos 5.5 VPS with multiple IP addresses.

I've setup the IP address alias for eth0  (eth0, eth0:1, eth0:2, eth0:3, eth0:4, eth0:5),
each with a different static address, using the Red Hat Text Mode Setup Utility (setup).

I've saved the config and rebooted but only eth0 and eth0:5 show up with ifconfig.

The folder /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices shows all interfaces scripts

but /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ only has ifcfg-eth0 and ifcfg-eth0:5 (which is what ifconfig seems to find).

Do I need to do anything else to make those aliases show up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you DO need the relevant scripts in /etcsysconfig/network-scripts. The easiest is probably to just copy the script ifcfg-eth0:5, rename and adjust the settings as appropriate, then restart networking (no need to reboot the server).

Comment: Thanks, wasn't just that - i think plesk was playing some role here. After adding those ips to plesk and restarting the network it worked again. Thanks for helping though!